# Function is Not Being Called When Button Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my JavaScript, and below that is the HTML Code.

```js
const displayClassChosen = document.getElementById('classChosen');
const classChangingButton = document.querySelector('#classChanger');

function whenValueChanged() {
  if (document.getElementById('shipClass1').checked) {
    displayClassChosen.value = document.getElementById('shipClass1').value;
    alert(document.getElementById('shipClass1').value);
  } else if (document.getElementById('shipClass2').checked) {
    displayClassChosen.value = document.getElementById('shipClass2').value;
    alert(document.getElementById('shipClass2').value);
  } else if (document.getElementById('shipClass3').checked) {
    displayClassChosen.value = document.getElementById('shipClass3').value;
    alert(document.getElementById('shipClass3').value);
  } else if (document.getElementById('shipClass4').checked) {
    displayClassChosen.value = document.getElementById('shipClass4').value;
    alert(document.getElementById('shipClass4').value);
  };

};
classChangingButton.addEventListener("click", whenValueChanged);
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="C:\Users\FirstName LastName\source\repos\testFolder\playerView.html">
    <button type="submit">Player Data</button>
  </form>
  <form action="C:\Users\FirstName LastName\source\repos\testFolder\HTMLPage1.html">
    <button type="submit">Combat</button>
  </form>
  <form action="C:\Users\FirstName LastName\source\repos\testFolder\HTMLPage1.html">
    <button type="submit">Crafting and Trade</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" id="shipClass1" name="shipClass1" value="Corvette" /> Corvette
    <input type="radio" id="shipClass2" name="shipClass2" value="Frigate" /> Frigate
    <input type="radio" id="shipClass3" name="shipClass3" value="Cruiser" /> Cruiser
    <input type="radio" id="shipClass4" name="shipClass4" value="Battleship" /> Battleship
  </form>
</div>
<label for="classChosen">Class Selected:</label>
<textarea id="classChosen" placeholder="None"></textarea>
<button id="classChanger">Click to Cement Your Class Change</button>
```

This is run by opening the file in Microsoft Edge using File Explorer. For some reason the function isn't called when the button is clicked. I've tried changing it to

```
const whenValueChanged = () => {};
```

But that didn't do anything. I've looked through several stackOverflow questions but none of them helped. I have gotten other function calls and button clicks to work so I know it isn't a connection error between files or the simulated webpage. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your script included *after* the HTML elements you listed, or before? (it should be after)

Comment: My original post had the header included, but someone edited it out. The script is in the header, but I will try it with the script at the bottom.

Comment: And it works now. Thank you! Didn't realize where you stuck the script was so important.